# Stange cache issue IIS

Tags: iis, iis-6

We have a website at a hosting provider. The strange thing is that pages seem to be cached somehow by the server.Even asp.net pages...

So when i update the application , or i delete everything aspx pages still work like they were there,even i clean browser cache.I get outdated pages randomly.Only workaround is to use a proxy server .If you make a request from another ip then most of the time it gets refreshed..Something this is boring as i keep getting error when there isnt one.Any idea of any workaround and how can it be by ip ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using Output Caching?  You may want to test disabling that.  Some people get burned by this if they don't know the nuances of how it works.  Or you can disable it for only aspx pages.

[image]

Comment: server isnt mine,it is share hosted.So i am trying to guess what is happening